# How can I make my html text containers more responsive?

Tags: html, css, image, padding, margin

My site looks like this:

DESKTOP:

[image: Desktop]

MOBILE:
[image: Mobile]

However, I need the text to be inline with the middle of the corresponding image (both items centered, so that the subtext isn't off-centered).

My HTML:

```html
<div class="col-lg-3>
<div class="container--wrap">
        <div class="inward-text">
          <br>
          <img src="green-up.png" class="center" style="vertical-align: middle;">
          <br>
          <span style="color: #9BDDB4; font-family: robotobold; font-size: 30px; vertical-align: middle;" "="">4.51%</span>
          <br>
          <span style="color: #ffffff; font-family: robotolight; font-weight: lighter; font-size: 15px">from yesterday</span>
          <img src="red-up.png" class="center" style="padding-top: 30px; vertical-align: middle;">
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <div id="txtdown">
            <span style="color: #EE939C; font-family: robotobold; font-size: 30px; vertical-align: middle;">1.80%</span>
            <br>
            <span style="color: #ffffff; font-family: robotolight; font-weight: lighter; font-size: 15px">from yesterday</span>
          </div>
          <img src="flag-ic.png" class="center" style="padding-top: 30px; vertical-align: middle;">
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <div id="txtdown">
            <span style="color: #AEAEAE; font-family: robotobold; font-size: 30px; vertical-align: middle;">text</span>
            <br>
            <span style="color: #ffffff; font-family: robotolight; font-weight: lighter; font-size: 15px">subtext</span>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```css
.container--wrap {
      background-color: #000000;
      border-radius: 15px;
      margin: 5px;
      overflow: hidden;
}
.col-lg-3 {
      flex: 0 0 25%;
      max-width: 25%;
}
.col {
      flex-basis: 0;
      flex-grow: 1;
      max-width: 100%;
}
.center {
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 135px;
}
.inward-text span{
      display: inline;
      margin-left: 10px;
}
.inward-text img{
      margin-left: 80px;
      float: left;
}
#txtdown{
      margin-top: 10px;
}
```

How do I do what I want to be doing?

EDIT:

[image: New]

I apologise in advance for the extremely messy `<br>`s that there are!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

br tags it is not the best approach, I try to simplify your solution, block with your image and text should be like there:

```
<div class="items">
    <div class="item red">
        <img/>
        <div class="item__text">
            <span class="percent"></span>
            <span class="description"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item green">
        <img/>
        <div class="item__text">
            <span class="percent"></span>
            <span class="description"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item grey">
        <img/>
        <div class="item__text">
            <span class="percent"></span>
            <span class="description"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.items {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}

.item__text {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}
```

And don't use be, use margin or padding, it is a more flexible and reliable approach.

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<div class="container--wrap">
      <div class="inward-text">
          <div class="flex">
              <img src="green-up.png" class="center" style="vertical-align: middle;">
              <div id="txtdown">
                  <span style="color: #9BDDB4; font-size: 30px; vertical-align: middle;">4.51%</span>
                  <span style="color: #ffffff; font-weight: lighter; font-size: 15px">from yesterday</span>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flex">
              <img src="green-up.png" class="center" style="padding-top: 30px; vertical-align: middle;">
              <div id="txtdown">
                  <span style="color: #EE939C; font-size: 30px; vertical-align: middle;">1.80%</span>
                  <span style="color: #ffffff; font-weight: lighter; font-size: 15px">from yesterday</span>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flex">
              <img src="green-up.png" class="center" style="padding-top: 30px; vertical-align: middle;">
              <div id="txtdown">
                  <span style="color: #AEAEAE; font-size: 30px; vertical-align: middle;">text</span>
                  <span style="color: #ffffff; font-weight: lighter; font-size: 15px">subtext</span>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Css:

```
.container--wrap {
   background-color: #000000;
   border-radius: 15px;
   margin: 5px;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.flex {
   display: flex;
}

.col-lg-3 {
   flex: 0 0 25%;
   max-width: 25%;
}

.col {
   flex-basis: 0;
   flex-grow: 1;
   max-width: 100%;
}

.inward-text span {
   display: inline;
   margin-left: 10px;
}

#txtdown {
   margin-top: 10px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Hi - thank you! However, although it is better, the text and bottom row seems to be pushed to the right: please see the new photo in my post.

Comment: So add margin-left to the #txtdown

Answer (score 0):

### **Step 1**

Remove all inline styles from each element and place them in CSS, as classes, along these lines:

```css
.percent {
  color: #EE939C;
  font-family: robotobold;
  font-size: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.detail {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: robotolight;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

---

### Step 2

Remove all `<br/>`s

---

### Step 3

Wrap each of the items as the following markup

```html
<div class="fancy-item"> <!-- your group -->
  <img ...>
  <div> <!-- flexbox sub-group -->
    <span class="percent">1.80%</span>
    <span class="detail">from yesterday</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Add the rest of your CSS:

```
.fancy-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

---

### Step 4

Add some bottom margin to `.percent` or top margin to `.detail` if you want to set them slightly apart.

---

You're done!

**Note:** You don't have to use my class names, use whatever makes sense in your context.

**Another note:** Steps 1-3 are the most important. They allow you to change all the items at once, if you don't like a particular detail, without having to go through each of them and do the modification. [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) is one of the most important principles in programming.